# Euler's phi function and Multiplicative inverse

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

We can solve the linear congruence with Euler's phi function:
$$105\hspace{3pt} X ≡ 15\hspace{3pt} mod \hspace{3pt}24 $$
Where $$a = 105, b=15,m=24$$
As
$$\phi(m)=\phi(24)=8\rightarrow (105)^7 ≡ 9\hspace{3pt} mod \hspace{3pt}24 $$
$$\rightarrow X ≡ 15\hspace{3pt}\hspace{3pt}(9)\hspace{3pt} mod \hspace{3pt}\hspace{3pt}\hspace{3pt}24 ≡ 15\hspace{3pt} mod \hspace{3pt}24$$
The solution is: $$ X ≡ 7\pm 8 N $$
Where N is a natural number.$$$$
But when we try to solve this linear congruence with Euler's phi function:
$$192\hspace{3pt} X ≡ 24\hspace{3pt} mod \hspace{3pt}27 $$
Where $$a = 192, b=24,m=27$$
We find that
$$\phi(m)=\phi(27)=18\rightarrow (192)^{17} ≡ 0\hspace{3pt} mod \hspace{3pt}27 $$
That's mean we cannot solve this second linear congruence with Eules's phi function$$$$
I know that the solution for the second linear congruence is:
$$ X ≡ 8\pm 9 N $$
I do not know why i can not solve this second linear congruence with Euler's phi function ? Can any one help me?

Comment: That method works only when $a$ is invertible $\bmod n$, i.e. coprime to $n.\,$ See the linked dupe for how to handle the noninvertible case.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242) is a proof that $a$ is invertible $\!\bmod n\iff \gcd(a,n) = 1.\,$ Note that Euler's $\phi$ theorem only applies to elements $\,a\,$ coprime to $n$, i.e. invertibles. They have finite order, and knowing any multiple $k$ of the order (e.g. $\,k=\phi(a))\,$ we have $\,a^k\equiv 1\,$ so $\,a^{-1}\equiv a^{k-1}\pmod n\ \ $

Comment: There are more efficient ways to solve such linear congruences, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $(192,27)=3\gt1$.  That's $192$ and $27$ are not coprime.  Thus Euler is not directly applicable.  $192$ doesn't have an inverse $\bmod27$.

In fact you run into the same problem on the first one.  Recall that the theorem says that $a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv1\bmod n\color{blue}{\text{ when }(a,n)=1}$.

One way is to invoke CRT when this happens.

Comment: My question is: What is difference between the two linear congruences, which make the first solvable with phi function and the second is unsolvable with phi function?

Comment: In the first problem, $105$ and $24$ are not coprime either, in fact.  So I think there's an error in that solution.

Comment: gcd(105,24)=3>1, not coprime

Comment: Yeah I had missed that.  You can't apply Euler there directly either.

Comment: but we can solve the first linear congruence with phi function as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

First you can divide all by three to make things easier:

$$192x=24\pmod{27}\iff 192x=24+27k\,,\,\,k\in\Bbb Z\stackrel{\div3}\implies 64x=8+9k$$

and since $\;64=1\pmod 9\;$ , we get

$$64x=8\pmod 9\implies x=8\pmod 9$$

and we get the solution.