# Is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ a simple $\mathbb{N}$-act?

Tags: group-theory, modules, monoid

Let $S$ be a monoid. A non-empty set $A$ is called a right $S$-act if there exists a map $A\times S\to A$ such that $(as)t=a(st)$ and $a1=a$ for all $s,t\in S$ and $a\in A$.

A sub-act of a right $S$-act $A$ is a non-empty subset of $A$ which is closed under the action of $S$.

A right S-act is called simple if it has no trivial subact.

For a prime $p$, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a right $\mathbb{N}$-act when we define the map $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}_p$ by  $(\bar{x},n)\mapsto n\bar{x}$. My question is that: is  $\mathbb{Z}_p$ a simple $\mathbb{N}$-act?

What I've tried: Let $A\neq \{ 0\}$ be a sub-act of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Then there exists  $\bar{0}\neq \bar{x}\in A$. Now if there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0 x\overset{p}{‎\equiv‎}1$, then $\bar{1}=n_0 \bar{x}\in A$. Then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\bar{n}=n\bar{1}\in A$ hence $A=\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Is there $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0 x\overset{p}{‎\equiv‎}1$?

Comment: What is a simple act?

Comment: $a1 = a$ doesn't make sense, as $a\in A$ and the image of an act should be an element of $S$, not of $A$.

Comment: @Kolja A right $S$-act is called simple if it has no trivial subact.

Comment: @Kolja The element $a1$ belongs to $A$ by the map and it is necessary to be $a$ by definition.

Comment: Please change the codomain of the action map from $S$ to $A$ for $a1=a$ to make sense.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Sorry, I made a mistake. I've just edited. Thanks.

Comment: I thought too much of this exercise. Am I right to assume that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of integers modulo $p$, and not the ring of $p$-adic integers? In the former case, there is a trivial subact, while in the latter the action in simple. Take the case $x=1\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and ask yourself when can you have $nx = x$ depending on $n$ (i.e. trivial action of $n$)?

Comment: @Kolja Thanks very much, Here $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is just thought as a set (not a module). We have to show that if $A$ is a sub-act of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $A$ is either $\{ 0\}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Only a comment, but isn't it a bit weird to tag this question as 'calculus' (or 'modules' and 'group theory' for that matter)?

Comment: Why are you excluding 0 when looking for a sub-act? There did not seem to be anything about that in the definition.

Comment: I agree with @TobiasKildetoft , $A$ is just a set, so there is no precedence of $0$ with respect to other elements. It would make sense if you give $A$ some structure and expect it to have a certain relation with respect to the action, like with ring modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed correctly, it is enough to show that for all $x\not\equiv 0 \bmod p$ there exists an $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0 x \equiv 1 \bmod p$.

This follows directly from $\gcd(x, p) = 1$ whenever $x \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$.

For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse or, for example, [If $q$ is coprime to $a$ then $a\mid nq-1,\,$ so $q$ is invertible mod $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2326598/if-q-is-coprime-to-a-then-a-mid-nq-1-so-q-is-invertible-mod-a/2326680#2326680) .

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Please note comment of @TobiasKildetoft, my answer was provided given your assumption that $\{0\}$ is ignored as a trivial sub-act. However, it doesn't make much sense to exclude $\{0\}$ because $A$ is only a set without any structure, so excluding $\{0\}$ makes as much sense as excluding $\{1\}$. There IS a sub-act, but make sure that your definitions of simple acts align with this exclusion.